# SSH connection refused on external network with the default username

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, sshd, port

I recently tried to configure port fowarding on my raspberry pi, to be able to connect through it from anywhere. So, I changed my box parameters to permit it.

[image: screenshot of my box parameters]

It seems to work, as my raspberry pi is responding. But I still use the pi username, and it seems to cause the rejection of the connection. When I try to connect to my raspberry pi, the following message appears:

```
PS C:\Users\MyUser> ssh pi@xx.xx.xx.xx

You are trying to login with the default username.
For security reasons this can only be done from a local network or console.

pi@xx.xx.xx.xx's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Of course, I can assure you that the password I enter is correct. When I'm connected to my local network, even if I'm using the ip adress of my box (the one with the ip forawrding) to connect to my raspberry pi, it works perfectly. But if I try from another network, this message appears.

I've been trying to search on internet how to solve this problem but couldn't find anything, event by trying to modify the sshd config.

Any clues to remove this behavior and allow me to connect to my raspberry pi, from a distant network, only with a port redirection (yeah I've heard about tunnelin, pitunnel, etc but that's not what I'm looking for) and without changing the username (Yes I'm aware that chaning it will allow me to ssh succesfully but that's not what I'm looking for) ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your friend: `\etc\ssh\sshd_config: AllowUsers`